# Hive bucketing is generating more files than expected, why?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a partitioned and clustered hive table (using hive 1.2):

```
hive> describe formatted myClusteredTable;
# col_name              data_type              
utc_timestamp           timestamp
...
clusteredId             bigint

# Partition Information
# col_name              data_type        
datePartition           string

# Detailed Table Information
Num Buckets:            100
Bucket Columns:         [clusteredId]
Sort Columns:           [Order(col:clusteredId, order:1), Order(col:utc_timestamp, order:1)]
Storage Desc Params:
    serialization.format    1
```

And I insert data into it like this:

```
SET hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
SET hive.enforce.sorting=true;
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE myClusteredTable  PARTITION (datePartition)
SELECT   ...
 utcTimestamp,
 clusteredId,
 datePartition
FROM (
  ... subquery ...
  ) subquery
SORT BY datePartition, clusteredId, utcTimestamp;
```

I expect it to generate 100 files for each partition.
Instead it is generating a lot more:

```
$ find /path/to/partition/dt=2017-01-01 -type f | wc -l
1425
$ find /path/to/partition/dt=2017-01-02 -type f | wc -l
1419
$ find /path/to/partition/dt=2017-01-03 -type f | wc -l
1427
```

Please help me to understand why this might be happening and how I can avoid it.

Comment: what is the table format?

Comment: ORC w/ snappy compression

Answer (score 1):

Maybe related to your Hive version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10880

Answer (score 0):

Seems that because of the bug described by @lake in Hive 1.2, I need to use a syntax that explicitly sets the number of reduce tasks:

`SET mapred.reduce.tasks = 100;`

And then explicitly distribute with `DISTRIBUTE BY` or `CLUSTER BY`.